# How to build tomcat-embed jars?

Tags: java, tomcat, build

My workplace requires us to build all the 3rd party dependencies and their transitive dependencies from source code.
I am trying to build following dependencies:

- tomcat-embed-core

  - tomcat-annotations-api
- tomcat-embed-el
- tomcat-embed-websocket

I assume its somewhere in the [apache/tomcat](https://github.com/apache/tomcat) project. I was expecting a maven/gradle/ant project. I did build the root ant project, but it did not produce jars for the mentioned artifacts.

How do I build the jar artifacts for these from source code?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the build notes in [BUILDING.txt](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/BUILDING.txt)? See "(5.3) Building the embedded packages": use the command `ant embed`. (Not sure about the annotations JAR. I would have assumed it's part of the core build - but maybe not.)

Comment: @andrewJames I missed that part. It does seem to do the task. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Btw. the annotations-api is in the same output, just the generated filename is without the "tomcat-" part.